# htaccess rewrite rules on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, localhost, url-parameters

I am trying to make a quick demo in my localhost with 4 parameters in the URL and display them with `echo $_GET['param2']` and so on. I have rewrite engine working for Apache, and there are no errors being logged. The page is displayed but I'm getting undefined index for my `$_GET`.

The first param will be the page I'm going to. 2-4 parameters will just be variables.

URL:
    http://mysite.localhost/index/abc/123/def

htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4 [B,QSA,L]
```

index.php:

```
echo $_GET['param2'] . ' 1<br>';
```

What am I doing wrong? The same htaccess file works at my work office.

Comment: forgot a 4th submask to the regexp `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$`

Comment: Thank you - but it is still not working. I'm getting `$_GET['param1']` is an undefined index.